# vuejs 3 v-if and v-else

Tags: html, vue.js, conditional-statements

hey I am building an spa app with vuejs 3 and I am stuck with v-if and v-else not working as intended

```
 <div v-if="this.isScroll" @click  = "toggleIsScroll" class ="spinner-container "> 
  <i   ref = "icon" class = "bi bi-pause-fill icon"> </i>
    <div ref="spinner" class ="spinner-border text-dark loader ">  </div>               
</div>
<div v-else @click  = "toggleIsScroll" class ="spinner-container "> 
  <i   ref = "icon" class = "bi bi-play-fill icon"> </i>
    <div ref="spinner" class ="spinner-border text-dark loader visually-hidden">  </div> 
</div>
```

the docs says that v-else needs to come right after v-if but I  don't know if it works if v-if has children inside it
i have tried to create the v-if section and v-else section in separate components and use v-if and v-else on those as follows

```
 <CustomComponent v-if="this.IsScroll"/>
 <SecondCustomComponent v-else/>
```

but it just renders both components always so how should I go about this?
can you use v-else on followed v-if element even if the v-if one has child elements before the v-else?

Comment: What does the toggleIsScroll click event do?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to displaying components conditionally, it would be best to go with `v-show` since it won't re-render every time when you make it hide/show

```
<CustomComponent v-show="this.IsScroll"/>
<SecondCustomComponent v-show="!this.IsScroll"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

v-if and v-else should work with children inside the element. Also you don't need to do v-if="this.isScroll" but just v-if="isScroll".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that IsScroll is set in the data, the `this` is not required.
Use `v-show` if you need to toggle something often, and use `v-if` if the condition is unlikely to change at runtime.

```
data: {
    IsScroll: true
},
methods:{
toggleIsScroll(){
.....
}
}
```

```
<div v-if="isScroll" @click= "toggleIsScroll" class ="spinner-container "> 
  <i ref = "icon" class = "bi bi-pause-fill icon"> </i>
    <div ref="spinner" class ="spinner-border text-dark loader ">  </div>               
</div>
<div v-else @click= "toggleIsScroll" class ="spinner-container "> 
  <i ref = "icon" class = "bi bi-play-fill icon"> </i>
    <div ref="spinner" class ="spinner-border text-dark loader visually-hidden">  </div> 
</div>
```